# Can a virus infect a virus?

Tags: virology

As far as I know a virus can infect any cellular organism from a bacteria onwards, including protists, algae, plants, and so forth.

But can a virus infect a virus?

Answer (score 5):

No, it cannot. Viruses infect cells, in order to [use the cellular machinery to replicate themselves](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Principles+of+Virology%2C+Volume+1%3A+Molecular+Biology%2C+5th+Edition-p-9781683672845) - viruses themselves do not possess such a machinery, so speaking of one virus infecting another is meaningless.

This does not mean that viruses do not interact: when two viruses co-infect the same cell, the progeny virions may contain parts of the genomes of both viruses. This is how [genetic recombination occurs in HIV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_recombination#RNA_virus_recombination).

An even more famous example is gene reshuffling of influenza viruses, where an animal virus exchanges its genes with a human virus, producing a new human strain. In the popular culture some of these a famously named after animals whose virus contributed or animals where the reshuffling has occured (bird's flu, swine flu, etc.)

**Update**
It is worth mentioning [the satellite viruses](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_(biology)), which are viruses that lack the proteins necessary to catalize the replication and possibly even the genes coding for their capsid proteins (in which case they are more properly called *satellite nucleic acids* rather than *satellite viruses*). These viruses are dependent on a *helper virus* to carry the missing genes. This is not characterized as parasitism, but it is rather close.

**Update 2**
A special type of satellite viruses, called [virophages](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virophage), actually do exhibit characteristics of parasitism in respect to the helper virus:

```
Unlike satellite viruses, virophages have a parasitic 
effect on their co-infecting virus. Virophages have been 
observed to render a giant virus inactive and thereby 
improve the condition of the host organism.
```